# webpack dev server ignoring scss changes

Tags: javascript, node.js, sass, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I managed to compress / compile my js and scss files with webpack. The scss file gets extracted by the 'extract-text-webpack-plugin' into an external css file. Here is the code:

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');
var ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");
require('es6-promise').polyfill();

module.exports = {
  entry: ['./js/app'],
  output: {
   path: path.join(__dirname, 'js'),
   publicPath: 'js',
   filename: 'app.min.js'
  },
 plugins: [
  new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
    compressor: {
     warnings: false,
    },
  }),
  new webpack.optimize.OccurrenceOrderPlugin(),
  new ExtractTextPlugin("../css/styles.min.css", {allChunks: false})
 ],
 module: {
  loaders: [{
   test: /\.scss$/,
   loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract("style-loader", "css-loader!sass-loader")
  }]
 }
}
```

When I run now "**webpack-dev-server js/app.js**" - it gets my changes in the js file itself (alert for example) but does not remark changes in the css file.

This is the app.js:

```
var $ = require('jquery');
require('../css/styles.scss');

alert('Hi');
```

I guess the problem is connected to the ExtractTextPlugin. Then again I have no clue how to workaround. Any tips or ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I got that going. When starting the webpack-dev-server, I'm just asking if we are in production enviroment:

```
const live = process.env.NODE_ENV === "production";

if(live) {
 ...
} else {
 ...
}
```

If we are **not** in production, it misses the ExtractTextPlugin out.

Finally to deploy my changes I type:

```
NODE_ENV=production webpack -p
```

One can also use a npm script to shorten this.